# Bootstrap - Modify Collapse Navbar Width Threshold? (Using Gem)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am on Rails 4 with the bootstrap-sass gem 3.1 (so, I am not using LESS--using SASS!).

My trouble is that my Bootstrap navbar is not collapsing soon enough. Because of extra navigation items, I need it to collapse around the 830 to 850 px mark instead of, I believe, 767.

Inserting this into my application.css.scss doesn't work:

```
$navbarCollapseWidth: 850px;
@import "bootstrap";
```

Neither does this:

```
$grid-float-breakpoint: 850px;
@import "bootstrap";
```

From what I am reading, the grid-float-breakpoint is a LESS variable and I am not sure if that is the SASS equivalent. Does anyone know how to modify this threshold using the SASS-compatible gem? Thanks!

Edit: Full navbar code if this helps:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site Name</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Rules<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <% @awards.each do |award| %>
                <li><%= link_to award.name, award %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><%= link_to "How to Submit", instructions_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact Us", contact_path %></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <% if signed_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "My Submissions", submissions_path %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Account<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Account Profile", user_path(current_user.id) %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Change Password", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
              <% if current_user.admin? == true %>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Admin Dashboard", admin_root_path %></li>
              <% end %>
              <% if current_user.judge? == true %>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Judge Dashboard", scores_path %></li>
              <% end %>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Create an Account", new_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Is your navbar successfully collapsing at 767 currently?  If not, can you share your navbar code?  Your second example with `$grid-float-breakpoint` works for me.  You may also want to consider using `$screen-sm` since that will change the collapse size for things like `.col-sm-`.

Comment: @cschroed Yes, I think it is collapsing successfully at 767. Just tried $screen-sm, that didn't work. I'll paste in my navbar code, it is just the standard bootstrap stuff but maybe that will help.

Comment: Hm.  Are you including `*= require bootstrap` in your `application.css.scss` file?  This can mess things up when you also try to use `@import "bootstrap";`.  If you have the `require` line I'd suggestion removing it.  If that's not the issue, can you update the question with the info about all the Bootstrap-related setup steps you've taken with your app?

Comment: @cschroed Removing the require statement didn't do anything. Thanks for your assistance in this. Not much to say for the steps I took, basically installed the bootstrap sass gem and then copied different site code sections (such as the navbar) from the official bootstrap site and pasted it into my application.html.erb. Put in the import statement in application.css.scss and the require statement in application.css.

Comment: I've never configured this with both an `application.css.scss` and `application.css` file.  You may want to move any necessary setup from `application.css` to `application.css.scss` (but do **not** include the `*= require bootstrap` statement in `application.css.scss`).  Then delete `application.css`.

Answer (score 0):

do you intend to collapse it in mobile device?
is so you can try adding this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

it will render correctly on mobile devices.

[Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_css_overview.htm)

Comment: Ideally I would like it to collapse on both mobile devices and the desktop.

Comment: yup, then the above code can help you scale them for mobile browser.